# yt-dlp cannot download file because of permission deny

Tags: apache2

I got vps server, uploaded my files, installed there apache2 (as th tutorial says), changed apache conf, gave all permissions to apache user (www-data) to r,w,x,
and i tried to download video with yt-dlp, and it return
`ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/8n5KYWCiQQQ.f248.webm.part'`
then I tried to run apache server with root account, then I gave the python script's ownership and permissions to apache user. But it is still not running. How to handle this error?

Comment: I have the same problem, except I run yt-dlp from command-line and apache is not involved in this

Answer (score 1):

Use the -P option of yt-dlp to specify a path to write the files into, and make sure the current user has write permission on this path.

```
yt-dlp -P /home/example https://youtu.be/zzzzz
```